# Query to return a field from a nested json using MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My database has data in the following format :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "abcd" ),
  "coordinate" : [somevalue, somevalue],
   "value" : [ 
   { "time" : 1,
     "characteristics" : "pqrs" },
   { "time" : 10,
     "characteristics" : "pqrs" }  ] }
```

I want to find the field closest coordinate and a time that is less than or equal to a given value.

Currently I'm using this query :

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    coordinate: {
        $geoNear: [latitude, longitude],
        $maxDistance: 10
    },
    "value.time": {
        $lte: 5
    }
})
```

This one returned the entire entry, but what I wanted is the field:

```
{ "time" : 1, "characteristics" : "pqrs" }
```

Is it even possible to just return this field ? What if there are multiple result and I just want the one that's closest to my `value.time` input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform an aggregation to :

- [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) items with specified `coordinate` and `value.time`
- [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) `value` array to remove everything < 5
- [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) value array
- [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by max value

Query is :

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
        coordinate: {
            $geoNear: [0, 0],
            $maxDistance: 10
        },
        "value.time": {
            $lte: 5
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        value: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$value",
                as: "value",
                cond: { $lte: ["$$value.time", 5] }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$value"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        time: { $max: "$value.time" },
        characteristics: { $first: "$value.characteristics" }
    }
})
```

Sample output :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("588a8c3080a14de2d654eb7b"), "time" : 4, "characteristics" : "pqrs" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("588a89327fe89686fd2210b2"), "time" : 1, "characteristics" : "pqrs" }
```

Comment: got an error saying E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):1:199

Comment: which mongodb version are you using ?